# How to retrieve text from HTML to Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

Hi I know there's questions already pertaining to this but I do not have enough experience to figure it out. I am trying to write a simple script in Python that periodically checks the earliest available date on a DMV website. Where I live, the DMV is backed up for months and after just failing a drivers test - I want to snag the earliest available date when somebody cancels their appointment.

Anyways, here is the HTML I am trying to grab from:

```
          <div _ngcontent-glu-c19="" class="department-appointment-header">Earliest date:</div>
          <br _ngcontent-glu-c19="">
          <div _ngcontent-glu-c19="">
            Monday
          </div>
          <div _ngcontent-glu-c19="">
             May 31st
          </div>
        </div>
```

Now, I am trying to grab that May 31st date so I can compare it with an Earliest Date variable that continuously updates when there is a sooner date than the existing one. Eventually I will have Python notify me by text.
I can't figure out how to retrieve the **May 31st** element and assign it to a string variable or list, so I can convert the month/day to an integer between *1 - 365*.

Please I'm new to Selenium and I haven't touched Python in awhile, I'm quite rusty and all help would be appreciated. If you need more of the HTML code then let me know I'll add more, I just didnt want to fill this entire page.

Comment: Hi, are you still having trouble with question?

Answer (score 1):

To print the *text* *`May 31st`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and *class* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='department-appointment-header']//following-sibling::div[2]").text)
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *textContext*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Earliest date:']//following-sibling::div[2]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *class* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='department-appointment-header']//following-sibling::div[2]"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *textContext*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Earliest date:']//following-sibling::div[2]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@_ngcontent-glu-c19='']).text
```

I'm not sure it'll work but it's worth a try

Comment: Not a valid XPath expression

Comment: Sorry lol, single quotes instead of double

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@_ngcontent-glu-c19=""]"}

Comment: Hey I figured it out, I got it to print "May 31st" using date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]").text

Comment: Yea but xpaths like that should be avoided, they aren't reproducible and will break if anything changes

Comment: Okay fair point. I used the Selenium IDE to find that target however it gave me other options like a css locator - .department-appointment > div:nth-child(4)
However, I couldn't get this to work in my code because I'm not sure what comes before the first .

Comment: It's also not very reproducible, generally you want a more human xpath that will work if the website changes. Hold on, I almost got it

Comment: I got the parent element using element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.department-appointment-header"). I'm still trying to isolate the children